# Copy target not honored when compiling .net 5 project in Docker

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, build

I have a .net 5.0 solution made of a main project (MainProject) and a set of plugin projects (Plugin1, Plugin2, ...).

After the build process, the plugin artifacts are copied into the main project's artifact directory through a Target Copy directive in their project files:

```
  <ItemGroup >
    <Binaries Include="$(TargetDir)**/*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyBinaries" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy
      SourceFiles="@(Binaries)"
      Destinationfolder="$(ProjectDir)../MainProject/$(OutDir)/Plugins/Plugin1/%(RecursiveDir)"
      skipUnchangedFiles="true"
        />
  </Target>
```

This works when compiling with Visual Studio.

My .dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./src ./

RUN dotnet build ./MySolution.sln -c Release --nologo \
    && ls -R MainProject/bin/Release/net5.0
```

After lounching:

```
docker build -t myimage -f .Dockerfile .
```

I expected to find a "Plugins" directory among the "ls"'s output. This doesn't appear, instead.

Weird enough, if I start the docker image and launch the same command from within the container, that is:

```
docker run -it myimage /bin/bash
```

and then, from the shell:

```
dotnet build ./MySolution.sln -c Release --nologo && ls MainProject/bin/Release/net5.0
```

the expected "Plugins" folder gets generated, with the expected artifacts inside.

What is the reason of this behavior? How can the problem be solved?

**Update:**
Launching the dotnet build command twice, seems to workaround the problem:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./src ./

RUN dotnet build ./MySolution.sln -c Release --nologo \
    && dotnet build ./MySolution.sln -c Release --nologo \
    && ls -R MainProject/bin/Release/net5.0
```

Now, after lounching:

```
docker build -t myimage -f .Dockerfile .
```

all expected binaries are in the expected directories.

Definitely, the problems seems to be related to the dotnet build command, more than to the docker environment.

Comment: Are you sure, that `WORKDIR /src` is correct folder to run `CopyBinaries` folder? Try to print `Destinationfolder` to check the real location inside container

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: I checked, but both the source and the destination folders are OK. It looks like executing the dotnet command twice "solves" the problem (See the update).